# Confidence interval and legends

Tags: python, plotly

is there a way to fully connect a confidence interval (CI) with a graph? Currently, when I use the suggested way for an CI there is an issue:

1. The line in the legend does not show the CI
2. If i disable the line in the legend, the CI still is visible in the plot

Is there a way to make the line and CI disappear at the same time?
Alternatively, can I prevent the user from being able to turn any lines off in the legend (so the CI never will be displayed without a line)?

Thank you!

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x_rev = x[::-1]

# Line 1
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1_upper = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
y1_lower = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y1_lower = y1_lower[::-1]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x+x_rev,
    y=y1_upper+y1_lower,
    fill='toself',
    fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
    line_color='rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    showlegend=False,
    name='Line1',
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x, y=y1,
    line_color='rgb(0,100,80)',
    name='Fair',
))

fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need here is to group legends. See the [documentations](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend). In your case you could modify your code as following

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x_rev = x[::-1]

# Line 1
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1_upper = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
y1_lower = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y1_lower = y1_lower[::-1]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x+x_rev,
    y=y1_upper+y1_lower,
    fill='toself',
    fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
    line_color='rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    showlegend=False,
    name='Line1',
    legendgroup="group_fair"
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x, y=y1,
    line_color='rgb(0,100,80)',
    name='Fair',
    legendgroup="group_fair"
))

fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much, rpanai!
The only thing I wish was possible (or I may have overseen it) is to also show the line WITH the CI in the legend.
Either way, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I see what do you mean here. Maybe one has to work on the legend. I'll try to have a look.